# what does PHP's ERA constant mean?

Tags: php, constants

PHP has had the "ERA=131116" constant since at least PHP 4.3.0 (probably longer): https://3v4l.org/XYZZ1

but what does it mean? what is it used for? `get_defined_constants($categorize = true);` puts it under the "standard" category, which doesn't help me much, and googling it doesn't seem to turn up anything useful, and the only documented constant i can find which sort-of looks similar is [IntlCalendar::FIELD_ERA](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.intlcalendar.php#intlcalendar.constants.field-era), which is a 0 (a far cry from 131116, I guess it is not related)

Comment: Run `git blame` on the source to find out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl-langinfo.php

we can see `ERA` being specified as "Alternate era."

[image]

I have never used this field, but according to https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_nl_langinfo.asp

it can be a parameter to `nl_langinfo`, specifying what `element` needs to be returned.

Comment: Note that the number is just a unique identifier for internal use. The specific value isn't significant, only the uniqueness.

Comment: @Quentin that's true. Basically we only need to care about `ERA`, rather than its actual value, so, if for some reason the numeric value of `ERA` would change in the future, the code not relying on the actual value, but rather on the concept represented by `ERA` would still work correctly.